# Виджет anketolog

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, виджет

Всем привет!
Может кто-то подсказать как правильно подключить виджет если я делаю это через сервис
Для подключения в шаблон у анкетолога есть пример, скрин прилагаю, но что делать, если через сервис?
Попробовала пойти через render.createElement
Скрипт создается, но функция будто не работает.
Хочу понять что не так

```
callEvent(id: number, token: string): void {
 const srcScript = this.renderer.createElement('script');
 srcScript.type = 'text/javascript';
 srcScript.src = 'https://anketolog.ru/api/v2/js/widget.js';
 this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, srcScript);
 const textScript = this.renderer.createElement('script');
 textScript.type = 'text/javascript';
 textScript.text = (function(){anketolog.widget({'id':${id},'token':'${token}'})})();
 this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, textScript);}
```

скрин с сайта анкетолога: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rZ5B.png